# am facing this error when i run my code AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

am new to python and learning through a project, i wan to build a simple program that just take datas from student and calculate his score average at the same time we store teachers details and students so am using classes but am facing the error as shown on image below
[the error am getting on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjx1t.png)

below is my code for student class i want to be able to take and store student subjects and score calculate the average score and give result to the user

```
class student(object):
    def __init__(self, standard, name, subject, score, age, address):
       self.standard = standard
       self.name = name
       self.subject = subject
       self.score = score
       self.age = age
       self.address = address
    def calc(self):
        N = input('Please Enter number of Subjects: ')
        self.name = input('Enter Your full name: ').upper()
        self.subject = []
        self.score = []
        for i in range(0, N):
            print('Enter Subject name: ')
            item = input().upper()
            self.subject.append(item)
            return self.subject
     
        for i in range(len(self.subject)):
            print(f'Please Enter the score for {self.subject[i]}: ')
            item = input()
            self.score.append(item)
            return self.score


student1 = student.calc('')
```

Comment: You need to create a `student` object, then operate on the object.  So, for example, `student1 = student(...)` / `student1.calc()`.  You'll need to fill in the correct parameters.

Comment: Perhaps what you have in `calc` is what you really wanted in `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple problems - not just the one that has been answered by @Tanishq

You entire approach is not ideal. It's much better to limit your Student class to storing data and handling its representation. Acquisition of the data should be dealt with separately.

Something like this:

```
from typing import Any

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name: str = name
        self._data: dict[str, float] = {}
        
    def __add__(self, __value: Any) -> 'Student':
        subject, score = __value
        self._data[subject] = score
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        r = [self._name]
        for subject, score in self._data.items():
            r.append(f'{subject} -> {score}')
        return '\n'.join(r)

name = input('Student name: ')
student = Student(name)
n = int(input('Number of subjects: '))
for _ in range(n):
    subject = input('Subject name: ')
    score = float(input('Score: '))
    student += (subject, score)
print(student)
```

**Console example:**

```
Student name: John
Number of subjects: 2
Subject name: English
Score: 65
Subject name: Geography
Score: 58
John
English -> 65.0
Geography -> 58.0
```

**Note:**

Numeric input validation omitted for brevity

Comment: @DackKnight this is even better, but i have a question on ` __init__` there is only one parameter declared which is `name` but below when assigning there is `data` which you used to store `scores` can i use this if i have multiple students and i want to store their data

Comment: @ezekielmhando The class is named Student - singular. That shows the intent of this class being limited to managing one student. You could consider creating another class (maybe call it School) which could be comprised of multiple Student instances. That would be a typical OOP paradigm

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing what you want

```py
class student(object):
    def __init__(self, standard: int, name: str, age: int, address: str):
       self.standard = standard
       self.name = name
       self.age = age
       self.address = address
       
       self.calc()

    def calc(self):
        self.subject = []
        self.score = []

        N = (int)(input('Please enter number of Subjects: '))

        for i in range(N):
            item = input('Enter Subject name: ').upper()
            self.subject.append(item)
        
        for i in range(len(self.subject)):
            item = input(f'Please Enter the score for {self.subject[i]}: ')
            self.score.append(item)


student1 = student(standard=10, name="foo", age=13, address="bar")
```

Your error:

- You are directly calling the `calc` function of the class, `student`, without instantiating it. (You can checkout [staticmethods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) in Python if you still want to do this.)
- The `self` is then treated as a variable name, and since you pass `''` as the value of self, it is inferred to be a string.
- This is why you get the error, that the `str` has no attribute `name` - because the `self` is a string and not the instance.

Some notes:

- You need to instantiate the class, `student`, and pass in the required arguments (as shown in the last line of my solution).
- You can merge the `print` before the `input` into one, as shown.
- You can merge the `calc` function with `__init__`, as mentioned in the comments.
- You are returning within the for loop, after you do `self.subject.append(...)`. This will not let to have more than 1 subject, and your scores will always be empty - since the function `calc` will never reach the score handling section.
- You might want to look at exception handling to handle the input of number of subjects, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Thanks @Tanishq this seems to work as i intended, and am new to python so am learning through this project